# Is it possible to have access to object values while defining the object?

Tags: javascript

I am defining an object inside a file I will export and require it has alot of config keys

```
var a = {
   main: { key1 : {label: 'one' value: 1 },
           key2 : {label: 'two' value: 2 },
          //etc...
          }
   selectedKeyValue : this.main.key1.label 
}
```

the benefit being that label can change often and I can always keep track of what it is if it ever gets edited, without ever needing to edit   `selectedKeyValue`

This obviously give me and error, but is there anyway to have access to the obj's values while defining it such that I can do this?

Comment: Only inside methods.

Comment: Nope, because in your example "main" is yet defined at the point you try to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use a variable without defining it. But you can do something like this:

```
var a = {
   main: { key1 : {label: 'one' value: 1 },
           key2 : {label: 'two' value" 2 },
          //etc...
          }
};

a.selectedKeyValue = a.main.key1.label;
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I went with.